# Filter on Date not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am doing a insert into a table, which is working fine.
But I want to remove data that is prior the year 1999.

This is what I am doing in the query:

```
SELECT Transaction_No, Item_no, Item_description, Date, Sales 
FROM Inventory_Table
WHERE
[Date] > '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

But it keeps showing prior data in the new table.

I have tried removing the '00:00:00.000' from date but still not working.

What seems to be the issue here?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

The Date field is a [Datetime] not null,

My query returnes:

```
Transaction_No      Item_No     Item_Description    Date                      Sales
001                 019238      Baseball            1900-01-01 00:00:00.000   100
002                 014952      Basketball          1900-01-01 00:00:00.000   250
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
254                 012459      Gloves              2005-05-05 00:00:00.000   550
255                 014563      Pants               2005-05-05 00:00:00.000   250
```

I want to get rid of all data prior to the year 1999.
That is transactions 001 and 002 in this example.

Have also tried without no help:

```
SELECT Transaction_No, Item_no, Item_description, Date, Sales 
FROM Inventory_Table
WHERE
Datepart(year,[Date]) > 1999
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `[Date]`? Can you give an example of a prior date that is being returned? Also unclear from your description if you are saying **that query** is returning prior dates or just you have some pre-existing data in the table that you are inserting into not meeting that criteria?

Comment: The datatype is [Datetime, not null]. I´ll edit my question, see above.

Comment: Your query works just fine. The behavior you see depends on something that you have not provided in the question. Try here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116001/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am doing a insert into a table, which is working fine. But I want to
>   remove data that is prior the year 1999.

Not sure I understand this correctly but insert adds rows to a table. If you want to remove rows you should use [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx).

```
delete from Inventory_Table
where [Date] < '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

If this query is to select the rows to remove, your angle bracket is wrong, should be less-than, not greater-than. Also, the `WHERE` clause goes after the `FROM` clause, like this:

```
select Transaction_No,
    Item_no,
    Item_description,
    date,
    Sales
from Inventory_Table
where [Date] < '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it to a date:

```
WHERE [Date] > CAST('1999-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
```

If you still have problems, you could try using the `DATEDIFF` function instead:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST('1999-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), [Date]) > 0
```

You can adjust the granularity as needed in the above example. It accepts `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND`, etc.