# How to compare datetime value in where clause?

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables which is inter connected with each other
 First Table is Category second one is Product and third is Transaction
when I trying to fetch data from first two table its working fine

```
SELECT     ProductCategory.CategoryName, SUM(ProductSell.Quantity) AS tq, SUM(ProductSell.Price) AS tp
FROM         ProductCategory INNER JOIN
                      ProductSell ON ProductCategory.CategoryID = ProductSell.CategoryID
GROUP BY ProductCategory.CategoryName
```

as far as I put condition for fetch particular data for date using third table that time its not giving any out put

```
SELECT     ProductCategory.CategoryName, SUM(ProductSell.Quantity) AS tq, SUM(ProductSell.Price) AS tp
FROM         ProductCategory INNER JOIN
                      ProductSell ON ProductCategory.CategoryID = ProductSell.CategoryID INNER JOIN
                      Transactions ON ProductSell.TransactionID = Transactions.TransactionID
Where Transactions.Date1>='11/1/2014' and Transactions.Date<='2/3/2015'
GROUP BY ProductCategory.CategoryName
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter on Date not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919251/filter-on-date-not-working)

Comment: `Transactions.Date1>='11/1/2014'` appears to be a syntax error? Is that in the original?

Comment: Also, depending on the server locale, those dates might parse incorrectly. If you try that on British format dates you're saying > 11 Nov and < 2nd March, which will obviously be no records. For this reason when using date strings it is better to use yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: @ChrisV I agree about the formatting but there is nothing wrong with the syntax. Well the spacing sucks so it is hard to read but it will work just fine.

Comment: What I mean is, is Date1 actually a field or should it be Date? Because otherwise assuming American locale I'm struggling to see much wrong with it.

Comment: Agreed. OP - try adding "set dateformat mdy" before your query and see if it "works"

Comment: I suspect that no records is the correct output for the query, the question is just why that is.

Comment: let me clear one thing Date is in mm-dd-yyyy format